# trying to get single item from list

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

I have a fairly bare bones mern stack and im trying to call getUsers and then retrieve a single user from the returned list of users.
however using [] doesnt seem to work.  It looks like getUsers correctly returns the list of users but idk how to pull a single one out

[image]

user-ctrl.js

```
const User = require('../models/user-model')

createUser = (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body

    if (!body) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            error: 'You must provide a user',
        })
    }

    const user = new User(body)

    if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
    }

    user
        .save()
        .then(() => {
            return res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                id: user._id,
                message: 'User created!',
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error,
                message: 'User not created!',
            })
        })
}

updateUser = async (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body

    if (!body) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            error: 'You must provide a body to update',
        })
    }

    User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                err,
                message: 'User not found!',
            })
        }
        user.name = body.name
        user.email = body.email
        user
            .save()
            .then(() => {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: true,
                    id: user._id,
                    message: 'User updated!',
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    error,
                    message: 'User not updated!',
                })
            })
    })
}

deleteUser = async (req, res) => {
    await User.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
        }

        if (!user) {
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ success: false, error: `User not found` })
        }

        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: user })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

getUserById = async (req, res) => {
    await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
        }

        if (!user) {
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ success: false, error: `User not found` })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: user })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    await User.find({}, (err, users) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
        }
        if (!users.length) {
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ success: false, error: `User not found` })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: users })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

module.exports = {
    createUser,
    updateUser,
    deleteUser,
    getUsers,
    getUserById,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the `getUsers` function (with parenthesis), and then wait for the promise to resolve, with `await`

```
var allUsers = await UserCtrl.getUsers();
var defaultUser = allUsers[0];
```

or

```
UserCtl.getUsers()
  .then(u=>u[0])
  .then(user=>{ 
     // insert code that uses the user here 
   })
```

Comment: i copy pasted those 2 lines but got an error when building: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function.  give me a second ill post the code for getUsers

Comment: no error with using "then" however i cant tell if its working.  breakpointing doesnt let me mouse over to see variable values, and my breakpoint inside createGitRepository never gets hit.  why is it intially just "u" and how does it translate that to "user"

Comment: What happens if you replace `//code that uses the user//` with `console.log(user)` ?

Comment: as far as i can tell nothing is outputted to console

Comment: even  UserCtrl.getUsers().then(u => u[0]).then(user => { console.log("test3");});   does NOT print test3 to console (some other error happens) - "Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

It's a promise, so try with async/await

```
var allUsers = await UserCtrl.getUsers();
var defaultUser = allUsers[0];
```

To make await work, put async infront of your method:

```
async createUser = (req, res) => {
```

Comment: i copy pasted those 2 lines but got an error when building: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function. give me a second ill post the code for getUsers